# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<U1') to dtype('float64') according to rule 'safe'

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, casting

When trying to plot the outliers using different colours on a scatterplot I came across this error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from 
>   dtype('U1') to dtype('float64') 
>   according to the rule 'safe'

My code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

CRP = pd.read_csv('CarsProp.csv')

priceMean = CRP.price.mean()
priceStd = CRP.price.std()   

CRP['isOutlierPrice'] = np.nan
testColumn1 = abs(CRP.price - priceMean) > 2*priceStd

for i, value in enumerate(testColumn1):
    if value == True:
        CRP['isOutlierPrice'][i] = 1

mileageMean = CRP.mileage.mean()
mileageStd = CRP.mileage.mean()

CRP['isOutlierMileage'] = np.nan
testColumn2 = abs(CRP.mileage - mileageMean) > 2*priceStd

for i, value in enumerate(testColumn2):
    if value == True:
        CRP['isOutlierMileage'][i] = 1

outlierPmsJoint = ((CRP['isOutlierPrice'] == 1) | (CRP['isOutlierMileage'] == 1))

colorChoiceDict = {True: (1.0, 0.55, 0.0, 1.0), 
              False: (0.11, 0.65, 0.72, 0.1)}

colorCol = [colorChoiceDict[val] for val in outlierPmsJoint]

PriceFloat = [float(val) for val in CRP.price]
MileageFloat = [float(val) for val in CRP.mileage]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(PriceFloat, MileageFloat, c = colorCol, linewidth='0')
plt.set_title('Price vs. Mileage with outliers')
```

Does anyone know where the problem is and how to solve it? Thank you,

Comment: That would be nice to provide the line of the error ... Or little bit more stack info...

Comment: I am using Spyder and it does not say exactly which line has the error (although it does in other cases).

Comment: See [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the scatter plot line. It should be:

```
plt.scatter(PriceFloat, MileageFloat, c = colorCol, linewidth=0)
```

I was putting the line width arg in inverted comas, which did not yield an output. However, the error message was very misleading. Next time I probably will pay less attention to the error message when debugging.